# Can i upload Javafx GUI on server?

Tags: java, heroku, amazon-web-services, javafx, openshift

I wanted to know, Suppose I've an application which is built in `Swing`. Let's say a browser which is built in `Javafx`. Now If i upload it on `openshift` or `Heroku` or `Amazon aws`. Is it going to play with that GUI on server. Please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have installed an X Window System (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) on the server, then no it won't work.  Heroku and OpenShift do not include an X Window System, and aws ec2 you might be able to install one if you want, and use it over vnc.